# How to convert an ipa file to a deb file

Tags: iphone

How do I convert a .ipa file to a .deb file?

Comment: Accept some answers, man. Also, what? "How do you turn an apple into a frog?" makes as much sense.

Comment: If that's the case, can you please tell me how to put an .ipa file that I made with XCode onto my iPod touch without paying the $99/year to Apple?

Comment: You can't. It might be possible with jailbreaking, I have no idea, but once you want your app on a device you need to become an official developer. And again, go back to your prior questions and accept some answers. Seriously.

Comment: I'm not exactly sure what you want me to do, but I have tried all of your suggestions, and none of them helped me achieve my goal.

Comment: With JB you can develop iOS apps without Mac at all. [theos](https://github.com/theos/theos) + [theos-sdks](https://github.com/theos/sdks) + [cctools](https://github.com/tpoechtrager/cctools-port). The only issue is that theos-sdks might violate Apple's copyright, and to avoid that you can [extract the sdks yourself](https://github.com/theos/sdks/blob/master/create_patched_sdk.sh). If so 100% legal? (IANAL)

Answer (score 1):

Your question makes very little sense, since .IPA is the extension for an application installed on the i(Phone|Pad|Pod), where as .DEB is the extension for a package for the Linux operating system Debian.

Based on your comments, the answer is: you pay the $99/year to Apple, and you can then deploy things to your own iPhone (there are [plenty of docs out there on this](http://mobiforge.com/developing/story/deploying-iphone-apps-real-devices)), or you Jailbreak your iPhone, and in that case, I'm not sure how app deployment works, but I'm sure there are docs out there for that too.

It is unfortunate that Apple has chosen to require payment for people to tinker with their own devices, but I guess that's why there are some many people Jailbreaking there devices.

Comment: I have imported my app to iTunes, but when I try to sync it to my iPod touch, iTunes give me an error message saying that it can't sync my app because it's not signed. Do you have any idea how to sign it?

Comment: Here is a good step by step on iphone deployment: http://mobiforge.com/developing/story/deploying-iphone-apps-real-devices

Answer (score 0):

Correction to the previous answer:
Your question makes perfect sense

iOS (and Mac OS) are based on linux.  Sometimes, when downloading apps for a jailbroken iphone onto your PC, these files will be have a deb extension because of this.

try this page for a couple of methods:
http://xsellize.com/topic/32674-converting-cydia-applications-to-ipa-format/

Comment: Unfortunately your `...xsellize...` link is 404 now.

Answer (score 0):

If someone wants to convert an ipa to deb I am 90% sure it is because they are not able to perform sideloading (e.g. I failed with [ideviceinstaller](https://github.com/libimobiledevice/ideviceinstaller)), and they want to install the package with [Cydia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cydia) without the need of sideloading.

Tools:

- rullinoiz/[ipa2deb](https://www.reddit.com/r/jailbreak/comments/hajnd7)
- Un1Gfn-obj/ios/[ipa2deb.sh](https://github.com/Un1Gfn-obj/ios/blob/0594fecb7d871789fb61a37db7ef849e9cafede2/ipa2deb.sh) - written by me based on the previous one
- alamshafil/[ipa2deb](https://github.com/alamshafil/ipa2deb/releases) - C# - Windows - GUI - I haven't tried it

TL;DR of how they work:

1. Create a `DEBIAN/control` and fill in some package info
2. Unpack ipa to a directory (ipa is kinda equivalent to [zip](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ZIP_(file_format)))
3. Repack the directory with [`dpkg -b`](https://man.archlinux.org/man/dpkg.1) or [`dpkg-deb`](https://man.archlinux.org/man/dpkg-deb.1)